# Advanced SQL Query to boost an operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables.

One is `Started_Games`:

```
level_id INT
user_id INT
```

The other is `Statistics`:

```
stat_id INT
stat_key NVARCHAR[30]
stat_value INT
```

My web application consists of a game with levels who only members can play in.

After starting each game, a function is called and does the following (In one SQL statement):
If there is not a record that contains both the `Id` of the user and the game level he started- add it to the table `Started_Games`.

When the user logs out I want to do the following (Only the SQL is needed):

First, select the count of the game levels he started. Then, update the `Statistics` table in a specific row with the `stat_key` = `StartedGamesCount`, and add to it the count that was found. After that, delete all the records of the current user (The "counted" rows);

I have never implemented several SQL statements in the same query, and this is what I have come up with so far:

```
DELETE FROM [Started_Games] WHERE [user_id] IN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Started_Games] WHERE [user_id] = @UserId)
```

Note it does not include the update process I want to execute.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you write your update statement , then include the update and delete statements in a stored procedure and call that from your code. Failing that you could just make two database calls, one to do the update and one the delete

```
create procedure sort_out_user @user_id int
as 
begin
  update ....

  delete from ....
end
```

[This might help](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/)

Comment: Making more than one database calls is exactly what I want to avoid. At this moment, I am not allowed to use stored procedures. This question was asked to help me finish a project I need to hand two months from now.

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.log_out 
(
    @UserId INT
)
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Statistics](stat_id, stat_key, stat_value)
    SELECT [user_id], '???', COUNT(1) 
    FROM dbo.Started_Games
    WHERE [user_id] = @UserId
    GROUP BY [user_id] 

    DELETE FROM dbo.Started_Games
    WHERE [user_id] = @UserId

END
```